# @Autowired Error creating bean with name

Tags: java, spring-mvc, autowired

I can't use `@Autowired` because I have error after running project. In error write `Error creating bean with name 'pupilServiceImpl'` but i don't create bean with this name

stacktrace tomcat log

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pupilController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private service.implement.PupilServiceImpl controller.PupilController.pupilServiceImpl; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pupilServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private dao.implement.PupilDAOImpl service.implement.PupilServiceImpl.pupilDAOImpl; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pupilDAOImpl' defined in file [/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.0.24/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/dao/implement/PupilDAOImpl.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private service.implement.PupilServiceImpl controller.PupilController.pupilServiceImpl; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pupilServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private dao.implement.PupilDAOImpl service.implement.PupilServiceImpl.pupilDAOImpl; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pupilDAOImpl' defined in file [/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.0.24/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/dao/implement/PupilDAOImpl.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at ...
    ... 58 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pupilServiceImpl': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private dao.implement.PupilDAOImpl service.implement.PupilServiceImpl.pupilDAOImpl; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'pupilDAOImpl' defined in file [/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-8.0.24/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/dao/implement/PupilDAOImpl.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    ...
    ... 73 more
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:147)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:89)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1098)
    ... 84 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [org.postgresql.Driver]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:245)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.loadDriverIfPossible(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:200)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildCreator(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:156)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:95)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcServicesImpl.java:260)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcServicesImpl.configure(JdbcServicesImpl.java:94)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:111)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:234)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:206)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildTypeRegistrations(Configuration.java:1887)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1845)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1930)
    at dao.implement.PupilDAOImpl.<clinit>(PupilDAOImpl.java:20)
    ... 91 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : org.postgresql.Driver
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl$AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:230)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:242)
    ... 106 more
```

**controller**

```
@RestController
public class PupilController {

    @Autowired
    private PupilServiceImpl pupilService;

    public void setPupilService(PupilServiceImpl pupilService) {
        this.pupilService = pupilService;
    }

    public PupilController(){
    }
    ...
}
```

**service class**

```
@Service
public class PupilServiceImpl implements PupilService {

    @Autowired
    private PupilDAOImpl pupilDAO;

    public PupilServiceImpl() {
    }

    public void setPupilDAO(PupilDAOImpl pupilDAO) {
        this.pupilDAO = pupilDAO;
    }
    ...
}
```

**spring-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:component-scan base-package="controller"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="dao.implement"/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="service.implement"/>
    <context:annotation-config/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="pupilService" class="service.implement.PupilServiceImpl" autowire="byName"/>

    <bean id="pupilDAO" class="dao.implement.PupilDAOImpl" autowire="byName"/>
</beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">

    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/WEB-INF/jsp/index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
</web-app>
```

if i create classpathxmlcontext i have new error

```
public PupilController(){
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("spring-config.xml");
    TEstst tEstst = (TEstst)context.getBean("tEstst");
    tEstst.print();
    System.out.println("hello");
}
```

stacktrace

```
SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext Context initialization failed
 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.springframework.beans.FatalBeanException
```

Comment: `Could not load requested class : org.postgresql.Driver` Dou you have Postgresql drivers available?

Comment: problem seems related to your persistence. Are you using a datasource ? How is it configured ?

Comment: i not added the postgres dependency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are creating the Spring Beans by component scanning AND by declaring them in spring-servlet.xml.

You should only perform one of them.

In addition, it seems your DAO wants a DataSource which in turn needs a driver for PostgreSQL.